# pygame collision with text display overlap

Tags: python, pygame

```
def main():  #my main loop 
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
score = (0)
score = str(score)
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('OpenSans', 30)        
textsurface = myfont.render('Level ONE:   Greenland', False, (0, 0, 0))        
background.blit(textsurface,(500,10))
```

the score is converted to sting to that it can be displayed on the screen but its converted back into an integer when adding the score

```
textsurface = myfont.render(score, False, (0, 0, 0))        
background.blit(textsurface,(10,10))
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    player_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_list, True)
    for enemy in player_hit_list:
        pygame.quit()
    player_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, coin_list, True)


    for coin in player_hit_list:
        textsurface = myfont.render(score, False, (0, 0, 0))        
        background.blit(textsurface,(10,10))
        score = int(score)+ 1
        score = str(score)
        print(score)
```

here i am trying to make the score update on to the screen when the character touches a coin but it overlaps with the previous score e.g. 0,1,2,3. so i need to get rid of the previous score.

Comment: you can just print(score) as integer with no conversion to string.

Comment: shall you add screen.fill(WHITE) to wipe out prev screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/replace text in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467863/how-to-remove-replace-text-in-pygame)

Comment: the background surface i am using is an image and i tried to blit the background  after the text is but it doesn't change it

Answer (score 0):

```
textsurface = myfont.render(score, False, (0, 0, 0))        
background.blit(textsurface,(10,10))
while running:

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    player_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_list, True)
    for enemy in player_hit_list:
        pygame.quit()
    player_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, coin_list, True)


    for coin in player_hit_list:
        textsurface = myfont.render(score, False, (0, 0, 0))        
        background.blit(textsurface,(10,10))
        score += 1
        print("{0}".format(score))
```

[Python/Pygame How to make my Score Text update itself forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733226/python-pygame-how-to-make-my-score-text-update-itself-forever)